# how subscribing to instagram realtime api helps me to get user/media details

Tags: instagram, real-time-updates

I have subscribed to instagram realtime api to receive POST updates for hashtag `#sudhir`
I am able to get updates to my server this way :

```
{"changed_aspect":"media", "subscription_id":2935881, "object":"tag", "object_id":"sudhir", "time":1362748903}
```

I don't find any user related or media related info in these updates. I found in **SO** that we have to hit their (instagram) endpoints explicitly to get photos/user info, inspite of subscribing to endpoints.

1. If we have to make request explicitly, then what is the use of subscribing to particular endpoint.?
2. What is the use of this json data (`{"changed_aspect":"media","subscription_id":2935881,"object":"tag","object_id":"nofilter","time":1362748903}`) we get in request body of our servlet. ?
3. Can we use this data in any way to get actual data of user/media ?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing useful I'm afraid. Once you have that information you know that something has changed on Instagram's end. You are then supposed to fire off the corresponding request. From your example it looks like you want to then do a tag/recent/ request and filter out anything earlier than the "time" variable.

Not the easiest way to do things unfortunately but they seem to have decided that the hard way of doing things is the way to go.

Comment: Too late Mark :( but still Thanks :) I did it as you said before your reply only :) :)